# Как сделать сортировку json файла с помощью асинхронного python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Пишу бота, хочу сделать таблицу лидеров по опыту. Вот такой вопрос, как сделать, чтобы каждый раз кто то пишет или относится действие к опыту, то json файл, где находятся опыт и лвл, обновлялся. Чтобы было так, у кого больше опыт, тот выше в списке.
Код обновления даты от сообщений:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user in message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send("Мой префикс **'**")
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        
        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 1)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)

        d = [users]
        await sorted(d, key=lambda x: x["experience"])
    
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

user.json:

```
"578950966439837744": {
        "experience": 192,
        "level": 3
    },
```

Comment: `d = sorted(,,,)` либо `d.sort(...)`, а то вы результат `sorted` никуда не сохраняете, а по месту сортирует `.sort`

Comment: @CrazyElf только ошибка выходит в виде KeyError: 'experience'. И в sorted и в sort.

Comment: А можно пример содержимого `users.json`

Comment: Ну скорее всего вы в `add_experience` тоже в словарь ничего не присваиваете или ещё что-то вроде того

Comment: Пример users.json:

Comment: "578950966439837744": {
        "experience": 192,
        "level": 3
    },

Comment: @Youtad  Как-то странно на каждой вызов дергать диск. Во-первых, словарь можно держать в памяти. Во-вторых, сортировать словарь не самая лучшая идея.  Используй sqlite и простым запросом получай игроков упорядоченных по опыту: SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY  experience DESC.

Comment: Ну во 1, если держать в памяти, то при остановке бота данные будут терятся. Во 2 я sqlite не знаю, только python использую, и делаю бота для тренировки и качества программирования. Бот сам по себе не планирую делать доступным для всех, а только для некоторых серверов. Бот включается вообще только, когда с пк запускаю.

Answer (score 0):

Применительно к данным JSON вы сможете адаптировать сами. А вот с помощью асинхронного Python  есть отличный неэффективный метод сортировки

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from asyncio import run, sleep, wait
from sys import argv
 
async def f(n):
    await sleep(n)
    print(n)
 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    run(wait(map(f, map(int, argv[1:]))))
```